# response.cookies не возвращает cookies

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Код:

```
hh= requests.Session()
response = hh.get('https://hh.ru/')
print(response.cookies)
CSRF_token = response.cookies['_xsrf']
hh.headers.update({"_xsrf": CSRF_token})
```

`print(response.cookies)` выдает `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`, почему не показывается/записываются куки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тот сервер не доверяет вам, т.к. по значению `User-Agent` это не браузер (там будет что-то вроде `python-requests/2.22.0`).

Исправляем:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
}

session = requests.session()
session.headers.update(headers)

rs = session.get('https://hh.ru/')
print(rs.cookies)
# <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie _xsrf=...
```